# undefined method `Then' for #<Object:0x000000073e1be0> (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, automated-tests, calabash-android

I am trying to add test step in a feature , step is as follows:
Then I scroll until I see the "item 2" text

and corresponding step definition is as follows:

```
Then(/^I scroll until I see the "([^\"]*)" text$/) do |text|
  q = query("text:'#{item 2}'")
  while q.empty?
    scroll_down
    q = query("text:'#{item 2}'")
  end 
end
```

and i am getting following error :
undefined method `Then' for # (NoMethodError)

Then(/^I scroll until I see the "([^\"]*)" text$/) do |text|

can some one  fix this step defination?, also if some one can give me a solution to pass multiple amount of data in same method will be appreciated.. i need to verify 20-30 different item on same page, i tried using perform_action('drag',16,18,30,16,5) function but it drags to diffrent level everytime.. and elements could not be located

I have almost fixed this ... :) the issue was i have entered two methods for same step ... and now new issue .. i am unable to break the statement .. and test do not end after reaching end of the page ,,can some fix this? where should i enter break statement

```
itemlistelements = ['item 1','item 2','item 3']
Then(/^I scroll until I see the "([^"]*)" text$/) do |arg1|
  q = query("* text:'#{itemlistelements}'")
  while q.empty?
    perform_action('drag',16,18,40,16,5)
    q = query("* text:'#{itemlistelements}'")
    end 
end
```

Comment: If this is `rspec` then it's possible this is missing the surrounding `context` block.

Comment: I didn't get u?? Am I making mistake in test step or test method..can you please correct the same

Comment: Can you share the surround code with us?

Answer (score 0):

You can write that loop multiple ways, for example:

```
while query("* text:'#{text}'").empty?
  perform_action('drag', 16, 18, 40, 16, 5)
end
```

or you can use 'element_exists' like this:

```
until element_exists("* text:'#{text}'")
  perform_action('drag', 16, 18, 40, 16, 5)
end
```

I would go for the second one.

You can refer to this [link](https://relishapp.com/womply/ruby-style-guide/docs/syntax) for more information on style guide and try using [rubocop](http://batsov.com/rubocop/) in your IDE